# Comma in Objective-C

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, syntax, comma-operator

I've just seen this in another question and thought the comma must be a typo

```
[controller release], controller = nil;
```

I'm using ARC so didn't use `release`, but I tested this myself the following code and found that it compiled and ran fine.

```
NSObject *a = [NSObject new];
[a copy], a=nil;
```

I was under the impression that the comma was only used for separating lists and multiple assignments of the same type:

```
NSArray *a = @[@"1", @"two", /*etc*/]; 
int a, b, c, d;
```

---

**Actual Question:**

Is it as simple as: The comma can be used to separate commands? Are there any other rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *comma operator* is a C-language construct.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type). The comma operator has the
>   lowest precedence of any C operator, and acts as a sequence point. The
>   use of the comma token as an operator is distinct from its use in
>   function calls and definitions, variable declarations, enum
>   declarations, and similar constructs, where it acts as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the comma is used as a replacement for the semi-colon. It doesn't make a difference if you use `,` or `;` in your examples.

Refer to this question for details: [Effect of using a comma instead of a semi-colon in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2087026/550177)