# Condition in for loop of C

Tags: c, loops

Today I made a typo, and then found below code can be compiled successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;1,2,3,4,5;i++)
        printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

I don't understand why

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

can be treated as a condition?

Comment: `i < (1,2,3,4,5)` would make for a more entertaining condition (and would stop your infinite loop in the process).

Comment: got it, it equals to `i < 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the **comma operator**. The value of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` is 5.

More generally, the value of `a, b` is `b`. Also, the value of `f(), g()` is the return value of `g()`, but both subexpressions `f()` and `g()` are evaluated, so both functions are called.

Answer (score 5):

Your `for` condition is the expression `1,2,3,4,5`. This expression is evaluated using [C's comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087026/effect-of-using-a-comma-instead-of-a-semi-colon-in-c-and-c) and yields `5`. The value `5` is a valid boolean expression that is true, therefore resulting in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As others say it's .always true and the comma operator yields 5, hence the loop will repeat infinite times

You can verify it by replacing **5** with **0** . Like this **1,2,3,4,0**

Here **0** is false, hence the condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `1,2,3,4,5` can be treated as a condition.

The output of `1,2,3,4,5` is 5.

In fact, you need not specify any condition in `for` loop.

`for(;;)` is a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop:

```
for( E1; E2; E3 )
  IB
```

with expressions E1, E2, E3 and an instruction IB is equivalent to a `while` loop:

```
E1;
while( E2 )
{
    IB;
    E3;
}
```

The only exception is E2, which must be present in `while` loop condition whilst may be omitted in a `for`loop condition (and then it is considered equal 1).

So, as others already said, your `1,2,3,4,5` is a *comma expression* equivalent to a constant `5`, making the loop looping infinitely.

Answer (score -1):

See that this code runs... but the for loop continues indefinitely. The condition **1,2,3,4,5** is always verified.
The compiler accepts more that one conditions in for loops. For example:

```
for(i=0, j=0; i<X, j>y; i++, j--)
    //.....
```

So **1,2,3,4,5** are five conditions (not one) and all these conditions are verified (in fact, these numbers are all different from 0 so they're always *true*).

Comment: Wrong, this is one condition. Evaluating of 1 through 4 does not affect evaluating of 5, which solely defines the final value of a condition. Note the difference between comma operator `,` and boolean `&&` operator.

Answer (score -2):

// try to know the meaning of condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=0;
  if(i<=5) // try this
  {
    printf("%d\n",i); 
    i++;   // increment i 
  }

}
```